# Making virtual keyboard

Tags: java, swing

I am making a virtual keyboard with Java as a personal project and I have one main concern regarding its implementation. For a virtual keyboard to work, the user muse be able to click on the buttons without changing the focus from the program they are typing in. How would I go about doing this with Java? I read some of the Oracle docs and couldn't find anything that deals with this GUI property. Any help? Thanks, I appreciate it.

Comment: You realize that windows already has this tool built in; it's called "on screen keyboard"

Comment: The answer depends on the implementation...

Comment: I think jnativehook can help you with this.

Answer (score 0):

Making a virtual keyboard with Java is actually not possible. You would have to send events to another running program instead of the current program, which is impossible without native methods, and then it isn't portable.